# Using static context engine ID with SNMP Exporter (Prometheus)

Tags: snmp, prometheus, exporter

I'm tring to run snmp-exporter (Prometheus) with static context-engine-id (SNMP v3 option). 
But I cannot find that setting in "SNMP Exporter Config Generator".
(https://github.com/prometheus/snmp_exporter/tree/master/generator)

How to configure context-engine-id in snmp-exporter/snmp-exporter-config-gen ?
(Or not supported yet ?)

I found -E option in snmpwalk -h.
That is what I seek in snmp-exporter (config-gen).

```sh
$ snmpwalk -h
USAGE: snmpwalk [OPTIONS] AGENT [OID]
  Version:  5.6.2.1

<snip>

SNMP Version 3 specific
  -a PROTOCOL       set authentication protocol (MD5|SHA)
  -A PASSPHRASE     set authentication protocol pass phrase
  -e ENGINE-ID      set security engine ID (e.g. 800000020109840301)
  -E ENGINE-ID      set context engine ID (e.g. 800000020109840301)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not presently supported. If you send a PR, it can be added.